# get_post_meta always returns an array

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using the following code to enable an if/else statement.

```
<?php
$types = array('.pdf', '.doc', '.xls');
$filename = array(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mjwlink-url', TRUE));
if(0 < count(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $filename), $types))) {
   echo 'One';
} else {
   echo var_dump($filename);
}?>
```

The problem I have is that get_post_meta always returns an array in the format even when $single is set to true

`array(1) { [0]=> string(34) "http://www.crimeandjustice.org.uk/" }`

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Compare a string like `http://www.crimeandjustice.org.uk` against `.pdf`, `.doc`, `.xls`? That doesn't seem like it would work...

Comment: Look for links ending in a filename and if so display a different image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It always returns an array because you are executing the `get_post_meta` function *within* the `array` language construct. According to the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) `get_post_meta` will *not* return an array if the third param is set to `true`. Therefore, swap:

```
$filename = array(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mjwlink-url', true));
```

to

```
$filename = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mjwlink-url', true);
```

Just out of curiosity, the logic within the `if` statement will only work on an array, if you remove the `array` construct your `if` statement will fail.

Comment: I still get an array using the "$filename = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'mjwlink-url', TRUE);" method. I am using it inside a loop...is this the problem?